# Dockerfile copying war to local linked volume

Tags: dockerfile, coreos

I have a note app that I am building with a Dockerfile in the maven app.
I want to copy the artifact note-1.0.war to local linked volume to folder like webapps.  So far I have the following in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:latest
MAINTAINER Sonam <emailme@gmail.com>
RUN apt-get update 

WORKDIR /code

#Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

#Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /code/src
RUN ["mvn", "clean"]
#RUN ["mvn", "install"]
RUN ["mvn", "install", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"]
RUN mkdir webapps

COPY note-1.0.war webapps
#COPY code/target/note-1.0.war webapps
```

Unfortunately, I keep seeing the "no such file or directory" at the COPY statement. The following is the error from build on Docker hub:

```
...
---> bd555aecadbd

Removing intermediate container 69c09945f954

Step 11 : RUN mkdir webapps

 ---> Running in 3d114c40caee

 ---> 184903fa1041

Removing intermediate container 3d114c40caee

Step 12 : COPY note-1.0.war webapps

lstat note-1.0.war: no such file or directory
```

How can I copy the war file to a "webapps" folder that I executed in

```
RUN mkdir webapps
```

thanks

Comment: The error is not about folder webapps, but about note-1.0.war that seems not present in your local working directory.

Comment: yes, it seems it is not able to find it.  Do you know how I can make it so it "finds" it and to copy it?

Comment: Did you double.check you have note-1.0.war in the same directory where you stored Dockerfile? Look at for details about COPY https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy

Comment: I see that it is copying the war to : [INFO] Installing /code/target/note-1.0.war to /root/.m2/repository/note/note/1.0/note-1.0.war .  I have tried copying from /code/target/note-1.0.war but it seems like the image has been destroyed or something.  So not sure how to capture the war so I can copy it to another place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy) instruction copies new files or directories from `<src>` and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path `<dest>`.
In your example the docker build is looking for `note-1.0.war` in the same directory than Dockerfile.
If I understand your intention, you want to copy a file inside the image that is build from previous `RUN` in Dockerfile.
So you should use something like

```
RUN cp /code/target/note-1.0.war /code/webapps
```